# How to get Amazon product details using Amazon barcode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-product-api

I got some barcodes of Amazon products and I'm finding a way to get their details from any API available. I checked amazon product advertising API 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html

but still couldn't find any method to get data from amazon barcode. Is there any other API/ Method available to fetch product data?

Answer (score 0):

You found the right method. Try using `IdType` UPC or EAN.